# Separating data that comes from two different target functions

Tags: mixed-model, residuals

I'd like to classify data points as coming from one target function $f_1(x)$ or another $f_2(x)$.

These target functions are very similar, except one contains an interaction term described below:

$$f_1(x) = w_1x_1 + w_2x_2$$ 
and 
$$f_2(x) = w_1x_1 + w_2x_2 + w_3x_1x_2$$

Which I combine into a single target function:
$$f(x) = w_1x_1 + w_2x_2 + x_{int}*(w_3x_1x_2)$$ where $x_{int}$ is 1 when a sample has the interaction term, and 0 otherwise.

I'm looking for a method to separate the data. What I have currently tried is the following, which is to create a linear model of the data assuming $f_1$, and using the residuals in the model to classify samples into either $f_1$ or $f_2$.

Here is some code that recreates my attempt in R:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

make_target_function = function(w_x1, w_x2, w_interact){
    fn = function(x1, x2, x_int){
        output = x1 * w_x1 +
                 x2 * w_x2 +
                 if_else(x_int, x1 * x2 * w_interact, 0)
        return(output)
    }
    return(fn)
}

target_function = make_target_function(10, 5, 5)
```

Now we create a set of samples:

```
sample_size = 10000

data = data.frame(
x1 = sample(c(0,1), sample_size, replace =TRUE, prob = c(0.5,0.5)),
x2 = sample(c(0,1), sample_size, replace =TRUE, prob = c(0.5,0.5)),
x_int = sample(c(TRUE,FALSE), sample_size, replace =TRUE, prob = c(0.05,0.95))) # for few samples, x1 and x2 interact, for others they do not
head(data)
  x1 x2 x_int
1  1  0       FALSE
2  1  1       FALSE
3  1  1       FALSE
4  0  0       FALSE
5  0  0       FALSE
6  1  0       FALSE
```

I then create the output for the target funciton:

```
data = mutate(data,
              true_output = target_function(x1, x2, x_int), # Sometimes x1 and x2 interact
              measured_output = true_output + rnorm(n(), sd=0.01))
head(data)
  x1 x2 x_int true_output measured_output
1  1  0       FALSE          10     9.991204535
2  1  1       FALSE          15    15.009449582
3  1  1       FALSE          15    15.016670831
4  0  0       FALSE           0    -0.004850586
5  0  0       FALSE           0     0.015655220
6  1  0       FALSE          10    10.011225986
```

I then build a linear model assuming the simple target function $f_1$

```
simple_linear_model = lm(measured_output ~ x1 + x2, data = data)

simple_linear_model

Call:
lm(formula = measured_output ~ x1 + x2, data = data)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           x1           x2  
   -0.05904     10.11904      5.12181
```

And lastly, I calculate the residuals from my model and data:

```
data$prediction = predict(simple_linear_model)

data = data %>%
    mutate(residual = measured_output - prediction,
           abs_residual = abs(residual))
```

And as we can see from the following plot, the residuals are predictive of whether the sample had the interaction term or not (sometimes)

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = abs_residual, fill = x_int)) + 
    geom_density(alpha=0.3)
```

[image]